# Buttons are not working on single click Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mouseclick-event

In my wpf app, My buttons are not working on single click. I've Edit button for changing dataTemplate of ListBox items. But, I need to click button two times to edit. also for right click event, I need to click twice. Double click event works fine. Why this happens? Where could be the problem?

C# code for Right click event and Edit button:

```
private void listBox1_MouseRightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToDelete = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)listBox1.SelectedItem;

        if(entryToDelete!=null)
        {
            MessageBoxResult Result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete Confirmation", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

            if (Result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                Globals._globalController.harvestManager.deleteHarvestEntry(entryToDelete);
                listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Delete operation Terminated");
            }
        }
    }

    private void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.ItemTemplate == (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate"))
        {
            listBox1.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("EditableDataTemplate");
            EditButton.Content = "Done Editing";
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (!item.isSynced)
                {
                    ValidateEntry(item);
                    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.updateHarvestEntry(item);
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Entry Updated");
                }
                listBox1.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate");
                EditButton.Content = "Edit";
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's probably something to do with the ListBoxItem template, but it's hard to predict without more details. Each listbox item reacts to clicks in order to change the selection state, so that might be one cause. Try looking at the structure of the controls with something like Snoop or WPF Inspector to get a good sense of what's going on. You can pretty much edit your question to remove the code since that's not really related to the actual question and only adds noise...

Comment: @MicrosoftDN As you said, I've added code. But as Alex Paven said, I also think that code is not related to actual question.

Comment: probably some other element catches and handles the events , use snoop to see who handled the events...

Comment: In Wpf Application if we click once it takes as listbox event, later if we click second time it fires the child item event. Hope this might be the problem

Answer (score 4):

Try handling the `PreviewMouseDown` or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` events instead. Sometimes the bubbling `Routed Events` get internally used by controls. For more information, please view the [`UIElement.PreviewKeyDown Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown.aspx) and [`UIElement.PreviewMouseDown Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx) pages at MSDN.